# Precompiled Headers when using 3rd Party Source Code

Tags: c++, visual-c++, precompiled-headers, precompiled, stdafx.h

I'm getting the following error:

> error C1010: unexpected end of file while looking for precompiled header. Did you forget to add '#include "stdafx.h"' to your source?`

Which of course is a fair error, and I've dealt with it before.  However, what's the stand procedure for dealing with source files from a 3rd party?  Should I go through every single cpp of 3rd party code and plop it in?

The other alternative is to stick in its own project and handle linking properly.  I'd especially love to not do this.

Comment: Disable precompiled headers just for the relevant files?  You can configure it per-file within the same project.

Comment: @RichieHindle Write it as an answer so I can credit you - though it might be worth explaining how to do it (though I do know how now that you mention it - thanks!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can disable precompiled headers just for the relevant files - those settings are configurable per-file within the same project.

Use Ctrl+click to select the relevant files in Solution Explorer, then right-click, Properties, C/C++, Precompiled Headers, Precompiled Header: Not Using Precompiled Headers.